# Converting Scala List[List[Double]] to Java double[][]

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, scala-java-interop

I need to a call a Java method from Scala. The Java method takes in a `double[][]`. I've a `List[List[Double]]` in Scala. How should I do the conversion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the combinators in `List`:

```
myList.map(_.toArray).toArray
```

Comment: sounds like he also wants to do a map(Predef.double2Double)

Comment: @stew I don't think so. The Java part expects a array of of `double`'s (primitives), and in Scala `Double` itself is also the primitive double type. So there's no need for the conversion `double2Double`.